# Why linq join is uni-directional?

Tags: linq

I am reading left outer join at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397895.aspx

```
    class Person
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
    }

    class Pet
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public Person Owner { get; set; }
    }

    public static void LeftOuterJoinExample()
    {
        Person magnus = new Person { FirstName = "Magnus", LastName = "Hedlund" };
        Person terry = new Person { FirstName = "Terry", LastName = "Adams" };
        Person charlotte = new Person { FirstName = "Charlotte", LastName = "Weiss" };
        Person arlene = new Person { FirstName = "Arlene", LastName = "Huff" };

        Pet barley = new Pet { Name = "Barley", Owner = terry };
        Pet boots = new Pet { Name = "Boots", Owner = terry };
        Pet whiskers = new Pet { Name = "Whiskers", Owner = charlotte };
        Pet bluemoon = new Pet { Name = "Blue Moon", Owner = terry };
        Pet daisy = new Pet { Name = "Daisy", Owner = magnus };

        // Create two lists.
        List<Person> people = new List<Person> { magnus, terry, charlotte, arlene };
        List<Pet> pets = new List<Pet> { barley, boots, whiskers, bluemoon, daisy };

        var query = from person in people
                    join pet in pets on person equals pet.Owner into gj
                    from subpet in gj.DefaultIfEmpty()
                    select new { person.FirstName, PetName = (subpet == null ? String.Empty : subpet.Name) };

        foreach (var v in query)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0,-15}{1}", v.FirstName + ":", v.PetName);
        }
    }

    // This code produces the following output: 
    // 
    // Magnus:         Daisy 
    // Terry:          Barley 
    // Terry:          Boots 
    // Terry:          Blue Moon 
    // Charlotte:      Whiskers 
    // Arlene:
```

I want to learn about outer join, so I tweaked it a little bit

```
    Person magnus = new Person { FirstName = "Magnus", LastName = "Hedlund" };
    Person terry = new Person { FirstName = "Terry", LastName = "Adams" };
    Person charlotte = new Person { FirstName = "Charlotte", LastName = "Weiss" };
    Person arlene = new Person { FirstName = "Arlene", LastName = "Huff" };
    **Person Momo = new Person { FirstName = "Momo", LastName = "Shawn" };**

    **Pet kaw = new Pet { Name = "Kaw", Owner = Momo };**
    Pet barley = new Pet { Name = "Barley", Owner = terry };
    Pet boots = new Pet { Name = "Boots", Owner = terry };
    Pet whiskers = new Pet { Name = "Whiskers", Owner = charlotte };
    Pet bluemoon = new Pet { Name = "Blue Moon", Owner = terry };
    Pet daisy = new Pet { Name = "Daisy", Owner = magnus };

    // Create two lists.
    List<Person> people = new List<Person> { magnus, terry, charlotte, arlene };
    List<Pet> pets = new List<Pet> { barley, boots, whiskers, bluemoon, daisy, **kaw** };

    var query = from pet in pets
                join person in people on pet.Owner equals person into gj
                from subpet in gj.DefaultIfEmpty()
                select new { name = (pet.Owner == null ? "unknown": person.FirstName) , PetName = (subpet == null ? String.Empty : subpet.Name) };

    foreach (var v in query)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0,-15}{1}", v.name + ":", v.PetName);
    }
```

Intellisense does not show up **person**. Why's that? I always thought you can swap left hand side and right hand side in a join. But apparently, you cannot.

Is there any documentation to explain this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Intellisense does not show up person. Why's that?

Because it was only in scope within the `join ... into` clause. But you're selecting each of the `person` values anyway, with this:

```
from subpet in gj.DefaultIfEmpty()
```

... so just use `subpet` instead of `person`. Heck, you can even call the range variable `person` if you want:

```
var query = from pet in pets
            join person in people on pet.Owner equals person into gj
            from person in gj.DefaultIfEmpty()
            ...
```

It's not clear *why* you were calling the range variable `subpet` though, given that it would be a person. Perhaps a misunderstanding of what `join ... into` does? See the [MSDN article on `join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311040.aspx) for more details, or perhaps my [Edulinq blog post on query expressions](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2011/01/28/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-41-how-query-expressions-work.aspx).

To be honest, it's not at all clear why this join is useful in the first place - it looks like a pet can only have one owner, in which case you're really just checking whether `pet.Owner` is in `people`. Normally you perform a grouping when there can be *multiple* elements. For example, the other way round makes more sense:

```
var query = from person in people
            join pet in pets on person equals pet.Owner into gj
            from pet in gj.DefaultIfEmpty()
            ...
```

Now you're finding every person, and listing their pets - or noticing if they don't have a pet.

What were you trying to achieve with your query to start with?

Comment: I don't understand what from subpet in gj means. gj is supposed to be object pairs. It seems like subpet is referring to the object on right hand side of the join

Comment: @user1978421: No, `gj` isn't object pairs - it's a group of `Person` references. It's not clear why you expected it to be pairs. Don't forget that `pet` is still in scope...

Comment: I see. It's like gj is a list of pointers. But why person get rid of null pointers automatically (if DefaultIfEmpty() is not used?)

Comment: @user1978421: Well not pointers, but references. And I don't really understand your question about "get rid of null pointers automatically" - have you read what `DefaultIfEmpty` does? It feels like you could basically do with a *lot* of background reading about LINQ...

Comment: I am more comfortable in Method-based Syntax than Query Syntax. I don't know when I should use which. I am trying to query something mutually exclusive in two datasets. It seems like the except function only exists in method-based syntax. So while I am writing Query Syntax, I need to convert everything into method-based syntax. it's so confusing

Comment: @user1978421: Use whichever is simpler for the query you're writing, is my advice. There are various methods which have no query expression representation - but query expressions are better when you're dealing with several range variables. It's a good idea to get familiar with both approaches, IMO.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're joining it into gj, person won't be accessible. Instead of `person.FirstName`, use `gj.FirstOrDefault().FirstName`.

Might be worth changing to something like this?

```
var query = 
    from pet in pets
    from person in people.Where(o => o == pet.Owner).DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new
    {
        name = (person == null ? "unknown" : person.FirstName),
        PetName = pet.Name
    };
```